# unable to start kafka and zookeeper using docker; ports 9092 and 2181 are already allocated

Tags: macos, docker, apache-kafka, port

I am trying to statrt kafka and zookeeper using this docker file

```
    version: '2'

services:
  kafka:
    image: landoop/fast-data-dev:cp3.3.0
    hostname: kafka-host
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
      - 3030:3030                 # Landoop UI
      - 8081-8083:8081-8083       # REST Proxy, Schema Registry, Kafka Connect ports
      - 9581-9585:9581-9585       # JMX Ports
      - 2181:2181                 # Zookeeper
      - 9092:9092                 # Kafka Broker
    environment:
      ADV_HOST: 127.0.0.1         
      RUNTESTS: 0                 
      FORWARDLOGS: 0              
      SAMPLEDATA: 0
```

but I keep on receiving this error message

```
Cannot start service kafka: b'driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint kafka-docker_kafka_1 (a741da2d21a00bb752fc169d579fa39bcdeef0cc88ec560d2e93b8fd287b8b5a): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:9092 failed: port is already allocated'
```

even after I remove all the images and containers ...

with "`sudo lsof -i tcp:9092`"

I see some process are going on ... but even after I kill them, using `kill -9 PID`some other appear ...

Comment: the process name is the following: XmlIpcRegSvc

Comment: Do this and it might solve your issue
1.docker rm $(docker ps -aq) and then
2.stop docker daemon 
3.sudo rm /var/lib/docker/network/files/local-kv.db
4. start docker daemon and recreate ur containers

Comment: @ShashankPai Not sure that steps 2, 3 and 4 are really needed.

Comment: @norbjd . judy mentioned even after removing all images and containers the issue persist . hence the other steps

Comment: use `pwdx [PID]` to find the working directory of that repetitive process and remove it if it was not needed anymore

Comment: I am using mac, not linux ... and when I try a similar command for mac "lsof -a -d cwd -p 5969", I get the folder, which is "/usr/local" ... not the very specific program that I can delete ...

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem; kafka and zookeeper were actually already installed locally and brew were running them in the background ... when I uninstalled them, everything was fine!

Comment: This helped me but all I needed to do was stop those services from running. `brew services stop kafka && brew services stop zookeeper`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that one of your containers is still using port 9092 (as `sudo lsof -i tcp:9092` shows). Run `docker ps` to be sure that there is no container running using this port.

Moreover, stopping containers using `kill -9` command is not the right way :

- if you're using `docker-compose` (as your example shows), you can run `docker-compose down` to stop all services (therefore all containers defined in your file). Alternatively, if you want to shutdown a container using only `docker` command, you have to run `docker stop <container_id_or_name>`, but I do not recommend that if you're using `docker-compose`
- when you issue a `kill -9` command, you're experiencing that containers are restarting over and over because you probably have defined a restart policy on your service (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#restart). The container started after the other one have exited (caused by `kill -9`) is using the same ports as the previous, so port 9092 is always used

Comment: when I run "docker ps -a", it is empty, so it looks like no other container was running ...